# SQL Create Modified Record from Condition

Tags: sql, linq, .net-core

I have the following table:

```
id     activity     xuser     isDone
---------------------------------------
1      abc          tom       y
2      def          tom       n
3      hij          jeff      y
4      klm          jeff      n
5      nop          jeff      n
```

I want to have the following result:

```
nCol     tom      jeff
----------------------------
done     1        1
undone   1        2
```

How can I do that in SQL syntax? Then how can I convert it into linq syntax? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's much more flexible to return the columns (xuser, donecount, undonecount).

Comment: @jarlh, agree... Can you show me the syntax if the column swap like you mentioned above?

Comment: You have to use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) in the SQL and there is no equivalent in LINQ when `xuser` is not static list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you end up doing something like what [@jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) [suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188993/2141621), you can achieve a similar SQL result in LINQ through a query more or less like this:

```cs
var xUserCounts = 
    from x in tableName
    group x by x.xuser into groupped
    select new 
    {
        User = groupped.Key,
        DoneCount = groupped.Select(y => y.IsDone).Sum(y => y == "y" ? 1 : 0),
        UndoneCount = groupped.Select(y => y.IsDone).Sum(y => y == "n" ? 1 : 0),
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much more flexible to return the columns (xuser, donecount, undonecount).

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select xuser,
       sum(case when isDone = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as donecount,
       sum(case when isDone = 'n' then 1 else 0 end) as undonecount
from tablename
group by xuser
```

(Someone else has to do the linq coding.)

Comment: I can add a sample LINQ query to your answer if you want

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Yes Please. With the linq syntax too.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, write it as a separate answer, and I'll upvote it!

Comment: @jarlh and Camilo Terevinto ... .You both are great! Thank you so much!